# Nested CSS Selector Testing in RSpec

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

Friends please I want to find a nested CSS selector in RSpec, for example, I want to test this:

`<h1><img class="gravatar"></h1>`

I'd like to emphasize both the h1 and img tags with the class.
I'd appreciate your contributions.

Answer (score 0):

I got this quick solution that works:

`expect(page).to have_selector('h1>img.gravatar')`